# TortoiseSVN folder did not auto refresh

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm currently using Collabnet Subversion Edge (v2.3.0) as my Subversion server and using TortoiseSVN 1.7.6 as my Subversion client on WindowXP.

Strangely, I encountered the following issue:

- Using the 'SVN Repo-browser' in TortoiseSVN, I access to my project repository.
- I created a new subfolder via right-click 'Create folder...', e.g. 'test', enter log message, and the subfolder 'test' appeared on the Repository Browser right away
- However, when I try to delete that subfolder via right-click 'Delete', e.g. 'test' and enter log message, the 'test folder still remain on the repository browser until I do a refresh, i.e. click 'F5' function key.

Why is it so? Is it a bug in TortoiseSVN?

Comment: It's just the nature of the beast :)

Comment: If you're assuming a bug, why don't you report it at the [designated site](http://tortoisesvn.net/reportbug.html#)?

Answer (score 0):

I worked with TortoiseSVN for like 6 month and I had this "issue" on a regular basis too, it's like soemtimes when filezilla won't refresh directory either.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue, but for those who find themselves here...

This problem was [reported and fixed in revision r23379](http://marc.info/?l=tortoisesvn-issues&m=135049991420481). If you are encountering this problem, you probably need to update your Tortoise.